# replacing part of a string in a boolean rule with indices

Tags: r, string, gsub

i need to replace this part  `X[,...]` in this string with something else

```
r <- "X[,1]<=-0.00595 & X[,2]<=-0.00605 & X[,20]>-0.00625 & X[,25]>-0.00615"
```

I would like to get something like this

`X[,...]` replase to `Q`

```
r <- "Q<=-0.00595 & Q<=-0.00605 & Q>-0.00625 & Q>-0.00615"
```

Comment: `stringr::str_replace_all()` is a good option.

Comment: Try this `gsub("X\\[,\\d*\\]", "Q", r)`

Comment: thanks it worked!!

Comment: @mr.T since it should not be that hard to come up with one yourself after reading the help of `?gsub()` or `?stringr::str_replace_all()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
r <- "X[,1]<=-0.00595 & X[,2]<=-0.00605 & X[,20]>-0.00625 & X[,25]>-0.00615"

gsub("X\\[,\\d*\\]", "Q", r)

# "Q<=-0.00595 & Q<=-0.00605 & Q>-0.00625 & Q>-0.00615"
```